# C# Draw doesn't make drawing

Tags: c#, android

I'm trying to make an app with eyes that follows your finger.
However, when I load my app, the drawing doesn't appear.
It loads the purple background just fine, but seems to stop there.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using System;


namespace BewegendeOgen
{
[Activity(Label = "BewegendeOgen", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    OgenView ogen;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        ogen = new OgenView(this);


        this.SetContentView(ogen);
    }
}

public class OgenView : View

{
    public OgenView(Context c) : base(c)
    { this.Touch += RaakAan;
      this.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Purple);

    }

    PointF punt;
    public void RaakAan(object o, TouchEventArgs tea)
    {
     float xas = tea.Event.GetX();
     float yas = tea.Event.GetY();
        this.punt = new PointF(xas, yas);
        this.Invalidate();

        this.Invalidate();
    }


protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        this.tekenoog(canvas, 200);
        this.tekenoog(canvas, -200);


    }

    public void tekenoog(Canvas canvas, int a)
    {    //this is the drawing
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        float radius, x1, x2, y;
        radius = 200;
        x1 = this.Width / 3;
        y = this.Height / 2;
        x2 = x1 * 2;

        Paint verf;
        verf = new Paint();

        verf.Color = Color.White;
        canvas.DrawCircle(x1 + a, y, radius, verf);


        float dx, g, e, f, d, ex, ey, radiusiris, irisx1, irisy1;
        dx = punt.X - x1;
        g = punt.Y - y;
        radiusiris = 20;
        e = radius - radiusiris;
        f = (float)Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + g * g);
        d = f - e;
        ex = dx * e / d;
        ey = (float)Math.Sqrt(e * e - ex * ex);
        irisx1 = x1 + ex;
        irisy1 = y - ey;

        verf.Color = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        canvas.DrawCircle(irisx1, irisy1, radiusiris, verf);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is this using xamarin? If so maybe update the question and tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized `punt`, so it is throwing an exception when it first tries to access it in `tekenoog`.

I tried this on my machine and it worked after I modified the `punt` declaration to:

```
private PointF punt = new PointF();
```

Hope this helps!

[image]